# How to group or sort pandas DataFrame where two unique id has the same value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

if I have .csv like this

```
ID      Value1      Value2
id1     yes         2
id2     no          2
id3     no          1
id2     no          no
id4     yes         no
id1     yes         no
```

So I want to filter and show only two (or more) unique ID-s that has the same values like that.

```
ID      Value1      Value2
id1     yes         2
id2     no          2
id2     no          no
id4     yes         no
id1     yes         no
```

So there were `ID`s which has more than one same values in `Value2`.
Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) - first remove duplicated per both columns and then filter only duplicates by one column `Value2`:

```
df = df[~df.duplicated(['ID','Value2'])]
df = df[df.duplicated('Value2', keep=False)]

print (df)
    ID Value1 Value2
0  id1    yes      2
1  id2     no      2
3  id2     no     no
4  id4    yes     no
5  id1    yes     no
```

Another similar idea:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(['ID','Value2'])
df = df[df.duplicated('Value2', keep=False)]
```